# Decimal list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, decimal

I have a file that represents a huge matrix:

```
54321

|  This     | Table     |           |
|:------:   |:-----:    |:-----:    |
| 6.75      | 0         | 20020     |
| 1         | 0         | 13663     |
| 107.75    | 0         | 0         |
| 0.25      | 1         | 27508     |
| 5.5       | 1         | 10964     |
| 11        | 1         | 19826     |
| 9         | 1         | 19817     |
| 7.75      | 1         | 27525     |
| 1.75      | 1         | 13005     |
| 5.25      | 1         | 2441      |
| 1.75      | 1         | 17250     |
| 142.25    | 1         | 1         |
```

where first line is dimension, second line is a tuple that looks like (elements from sparse matrix, line index, column index).

I have to read from this file the dimension and to generate vectors for matrix storage.

```
def getLineIndex(a, x):
for lineIndex in range(0, len(a)):
    diagonalValue, lineNumber = a[lineIndex][-1]
    if lineNumber == x:
        return lineIndex
return -1

def getColumnIndex(a, x, y):
line = a[x]
for i in range(0, len(line)):
    value, columnNumber = line[i]
    if columnNumber == y:
        return i
return -1

def read_values(filename):
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    n = int(file.readline())

    b = list()
    for i in range(0, n):
        b.append((file.readline()))

    a = list()
    for line in file:
        values = line.replace(",", " ").split()
        value = Decimal(values[0])
        x = int(values[1])
        y = int(values[2])

        lineIndex = getLineIndex(a, x)
        if lineIndex != -1:
            columnIndex = getColumnIndex(a, lineIndex, y)
            if columnIndex != -1:
                a[lineIndex][columnIndex][0] += value
            else:
#                 #addNewColumn(a, value, lineIndex, y)
                a[lineIndex].insert(0, [value, y])
```

But I receive this error:

File "source.py", line 31, in read_values
    value = Decimal(values[0])
    IndexError: list index out of range

I appreciate any type of help.

Comment: What is the state of values before the execution of this command ? could you print it out ?

Comment: That error message means that `values` is an empty list. Which most probably means `line` is empty too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line, which is `54321`, there is no space or ",". So splitting with space or "," returns None. Thus values array is empty. When you try to access `values[0]`, this error will occur: `IndexError: list index out of range`.
This should work:

```
for line in file:
    values = line.replace(",", " ").split()  //line number 30
    if len(values) == 0:
       continue
    value = Decimal(values[0])
```

Comment: @Biax you may want to make sure that anything is being read in that for loop. You have already iterated through the entire file and so your position in the file is at the bottom

Comment: This is a good solution for skipping over that first line, but you may need to seek back to the beginning of the file as well

Answer (score 0):

I think your `line` variable is empty, causing `values` to be empty, because you have already iterated through all the lines and put them into `b`, so now you are trying to read from the bottom of the file, which is likely reading empty lines. You probably want to seek back to the beginning of the file before iterating through each line again using something like this: `file.seek(0, os)`. Once you are back at the top of the file, you can use @NanduRaj's solution to skip over the first line and iterate as you want.